# Need help with my first college math class - multiple absolute value equation

Tags: absolute-value

There's an equation that we got assigned to solve in our first college math class. I was alright at math in high school, but I've never seen an absolute value equation similar to this one.

> |||||x|+x|+x|+x|+x| = 2018

I'm guessing we have to split it in 2 cases, one in which

> +x >= 0

and

> -x < 0

How should I approach this problem?

Comment: Yes, that's right. If $x>0$, then $|x|=x$, right? In which case can you simplify the left-hand side? If $x<0$, then $|x|=-x$, which should again help you simplify the left-hand side.

Comment: So the solutions are 5x = 2018 and 5x = -2018 (this one's wrong it seems.)

Thanks.

Comment: If x is negative, $|x|=-x$.  You get a different equation than your second one in that case.

Comment: Yep, I got it. Ty :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x \geq 0$, then $2x, 3x, 4x, 5x$ are also non-negative, and the LHS is
$$ |||||x|+x|+x|+x|+x| = ||||2x|+x|+x|+x| = \dotsb = 5x,$$
so $5x = 2018 \implies x = 2018/5$.

If instead $x < 0$, then $|x| = -x$, and the LHS is
$$ |||||x|+x|+x|+x|+x| = ||||-x+x|+x|+x|+x| = ||||0|+x|+x|+x| = |||x|+x|+x| = ||-x+x|+x| = |0+x| = |x| = -x,$$
so $-x = 2018 \implies x = -2018$.

Comment: I did get the first one right.

Mind explaining the second one?

Comment: Thanks! I got it.